# I'm about to give up on my first project with python which is making a discord bot, this will be my last question?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I keep getting errors with this project and this is probably the last one I'm gonna try to fix
here's the code that has the problem:

```
 @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))

        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]

        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)
```

and this is the error:

```
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\moham\Desktop\musicbot.py", line 104, in play
    player = await YTDLSource.from_url(queue, loop=client.loop)
  File "C:\Users\moham\Desktop\musicbot.py", line 40, in from_url
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\moham\Desktop\musicbot.py", line 40, in <lambda>
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 788, in extract_info
    if not ie.suitable(url):
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 413, in suitable
    return cls._VALID_URL_RE.match(url) is not None
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I am still new to all of this so please assume that I don't know a lot about coding, I was just following a tutorial and apparently I'm not even good at that lol.

Comment: It doesn't sound like `url` is a URL at all.

Comment: I strongly believe that *discord bot* is not the project you should start from, because you need to know basics. Start from official python tutorial or any other tutorial you will like, after that you can try to move further.

Comment: Alrighty then lol

Comment: Ya, I see a lot of people using elaborate libraries as their first project. That's setting yourself up for frustration. I didn't use any complicated libraries until I had already been programming for like a year. Learning the basics (like debugging and learning t read error messages) is far more important than immediately branching off into the more interesting stuff (unfortunately).

Comment: Thank you all for the advice! I will probably focus on the basics then.

Comment: As mentioned in a previous comment though, `url` doesn't appear to be a valid URL. You would need to double check what's being passed into this function. We can't say because that's not in this code here.

Comment: It is also easier to help when you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You define a function with multiple parameters and do not show how it was called (command and arguments). If the code can be copy/pasted and run easily then help happens quickly. Enjoy the debug, it's the fun part.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere BTW, you can generate that link using `[mcve]`: [mcve].